# Max switching speed on CMOS

Tags: transistors, cmos, switching, analog-switch, silicon

Is it possible to generate a 500 giga hertz square wave on CMOS technology in order to switch a circuit? If not what's the max frequency CMOS can switch?

Comment: Have you tried reading the data sheet of a CMOS IC to see what it says?

Comment: at such frequencies I think the IC leads would present a high impedance to the wave, no?

Comment: It won't be a square wave at that frequency.

Comment: Are you sure you mean 500 Gigahertz? Computer CPUs top out around 5 Gigahertz and need massive coolers to do so. 500 GHz is in the upper microwave region, approaching infrared. Normal CMOS logic ICs are limited to something like 20-40 MHz, so about 1/10,000th of what you're asking.

Comment: Yes it won't be a proper square wave. Also i am not referring to an IC.I understand that parasitics come into play at the IC leads.  I was thinking if CMOS transistors themselves can switch at that frequency. I see silicon germanium ones can reach to that level. https://news.gatech.edu/news/2014/02/18/silicon-germanium-chip-sets-new-speed-record

Comment: I've found an IEEE article about high frequency MOSFETs which are the devices used in CMOS technology. "... Record high combined ft and f max of 370 and 310 GHz ..." https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8656532

Comment: 500 GHz is moderately close to the maximum currently possible with more exotic CMOS transistors. A square wave at that frequency would imply transistors with THz bandwidth though, which probably won't happen anytime soon.

Comment: I don't think 500GHz digital is possible in the current CMOS technology. In SiGe, an oscillator at 530GHz was generated via the push-push technique. example: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6757424